# How can I create the large disks in Azure that are currently in public preview?

Tags: azure, hard-drive, storage, cloud, provisioning

Azure started supporting extra large disk sizes in September 2018 (as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-public-preview-of-larger-managed-disks-sizes/)) as a public preview, currently available only in the `West Central US` region.

I'm trying to create a new `S60` (4-8 TiB HDD) disk in a resource group located in the above region. However the disk creation dialog still limits me to up to 4095 GiB disk size. It even tells me that larger sizes are currently in public preview.

How can I actually create the disks described in the preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the link you posted:

> Try out the new Managed Disks sizes using Azure [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps) or [CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk) today!

You can't use the Azure Portal to create disks with these sizes yet. The document also states that this is one of the features coming later:

> Azure Portal support for larger disk sizes, and ability to upsize existing disks.